# pthreads broadcast when waiting in while

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have multiple (say `T`) threads that wait as follows (pseudocode)

```
while (a == 1)
    pthread_cond_wait(cv, mutex);
```

Another thread which currently has the mutex does the following

```
a = 0;
pthread_cond_broadcast(cv);
```

What happens after the broadcast? Will all the `T` threads eventually (depending on the scheduler) exit the while loop or will more `signal`/`broadcast`s be required after?

Comment: From the man page:  *"The pthread_cond_broadcast() function unblocks all threads waiting for the condition variable"*

Comment: @user3386109 what is meant by *unblock* here? after the broadcast, a single thread will proceed to execute. what happens to the other threads? will they still wait inside the while loop?

Comment: It means they are ready to run as soon as they can grab the mutex. Part of `pthread_cond_wait` is to lock the mutex when the condition is signaled. So the first thread that wakes up (and locks the mutex) needs to unlock the mutex before the next thread will run. The `while` loop has nothing to do with it. The thread stays in the `pthread_cond_wait` function until A) the condition is signaled and B) the mutex is available.

Comment: So the other threads waiting on the condition variable exit the while loop and now wait on the mutex?

Comment: The other threads do not `return` from the `pthread_cond_wait` function call until they have the mutex locked.

Comment: The code will not work correctly, because the thread doing `pthread_cond_broadcast(cv)` did not acquire the mutex, so the condition for atomicity of `pthread_cond_wait()` is not met.